# A question regarding path-connected space and homotopic maps

Tags: general-topology, continuity, path-connected

Let $X$ be a space. Assume that $a\in X$, and the map $c_a:X\to \{a\}$ is homotopic to the identity map $id:X\to X$.

1. Prove that $X$ is path-connected.
2. Prove that for all $b\in X$ there is a homotopy from the constant map $c_b:X\to \{b\}$ to $id$.

In 1: I need to show that for any two points $x,y\in X$ there is a continuous map $f:I\to X$ of the unit interval $I=[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$.
I thought of applying the def of homotopy,
And get that there is a homotopy=continuous map $H=H(x,-): I\to X$ (for a fixed $x\in X$) such that

$H(0)=H(x,0)=c_a(x)=a$ ($\in X$),
$H(1)=H(x,1)=x$
($\in X$)

So, for any two points $x,a \in X$ consider $H$ as the needed map (i.e. $f:=H$).

In 2, I tried to use the def of homotopy and part 1, but how to do so, if for example I define a homotopy $H:X\times I\to X$ as $H(x,t)=t(x-b)+b$ that indeed satisfy $H(x,0)=c_b(x)=b, H(x,1)=x$, however is $+$ have any meaning in a topological space?
I think maybe I need to prove here a more general claim..

Comment: Regarding 1 - you are in the right direction. The only inaccuracy is that you said that you want to find a path between any 2 general points $x, y$, but in your proof you only showed that there's a path between $a$ and a general $x$. Regarding 2 - you're right to say that adding numbers in a topological space makes no sense. try to use what you showed in 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint for 1:** Concatenate the paths from $x$ to $a$ with the path from $a$ to $y$. The following equivalence holds in more generality:

> A non-empty topological space $X$ is path connected if and only if there exists a point $a\in X$ such that for all $x\in X$, there is a path from $a$ to $x$.

Assuming this equivalence is known, then you are done with part $a$. If not, this can be proven using the same hint above.

**Hint for 2:** Since $X$ is path connected, there is a path between $b=f(0)$ and $a=f(1)$. The map $G:X\times [0,1]\to X$ given by $(x,t)\mapsto f(t)$ is a homotopy from $c_b$ and $c_a$. Try to concatenate $G$ with $H$ by performing  $G$ first, then $H$, where $H$ is the homotopy from $c_a$ to $\text{id}_X$. This concatenation of homotopies will result in a homotopy between $c_b$ and $\text{id}_X$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, in part 1, can I do it this way: let $f,g:[0,1]\ to X$ such that $f(0)=x, (1)=a, g(0)=a, g(1)=y$ where $x,y\in X$. By assumption that $c_a, id$ are homotopic we get two continuous maps $H:X\times [0,1]\to X$ defined by $H(x,t)=f(t)$, and $G:X\times [0,1]\to X$ defined by $G(x,t)=g(t)$, so the $f*g:[0,1]\to X$ is a path from $x$ to $y$. How to finish this if it is enough accurate? In part 2, can I say that since homotopy is an equivalence relation so $c_b~i_d$? (Or I just need to look at $G*H$ so it is a homotopy between $c_b, i_d$?) @C Squared

Comment: In regards to part 1, you don't need to consider the homotopies $H$ and $G$ here since we know there is a path from $a$ to $x$ (by the work you have already done in your original post). You just look at $f*g$ and show that it is a path from $x$ to $y$. In regards to part 2, simply check that $G*H$ is a homotopy from $c_b$ to $\text{id}_X$. @user726608

Comment: We know there is a path from a to x, since we're hiven that $c_a$ and $i_d$ are homotopic, right? My $f*g$ is defined as $f(2t), 0\leq t\leq 1/2$ and $g(2t-1), 1/2\leq t\leq 1$ so it is a path from x to y? For 2, I don't think I know how to show that a concatenation is a homotopy..@C Squared

Comment: your guess is correct, and it is indeed a path from $x$ to $y$. The concatenation of $G$ and $H$ is defined similarly to the concatenation of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: not quite. I edited my post to specify which $H$ we are talking about here. $H$ in this context is the homotopy from $c_a$ to $\text{id}_X$ and $G$ is still the homotopy from $c_b$ to $c_a$. The homotopy $G*H$ is defined by $$(x,t)\mapsto \begin{cases}G(x,2t)&\text{ if }t\in[0,1/2]\\H(x,2t-1)&\text{ if }t\in[1/2,1]\end{cases}$$